# Bootstrap Modal Changes Size After Hide/Reopen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a very frustrating issue with a Bootstrap Modal (Bootstrap 2.3.2) that I'm using for a file upload window. It is probably important to note that this is a nested modal, but this is the only instance that I'm having this automatic re-size issue. I have 6 other secondary modals that open from the primary Product Editor modal that are not resizing after they open/close.

Its also worth noting, that on the other modals that are not having this resize issue, they are not being assigned a custom width value.

Here are two images, the first is the first time I open the modal, the second is after it calls modal('hide') and then is opened again with modal('show');

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP4SV.png (first open) https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9xvd.png (second open)

This is the creation code:

```
$('#mediaModal').modal({
    show: false,
    keyboard: false,
    width: '60%',
    maxHeight: '600px', 
    backdrop: 'static'
});
```

You'll notice in the screenshots that it is sitting over the larger product editor modal. Once an upload is complete, or the cancel button is clicked, (or the upload button is clicked and there are no files to upload), it simple calls:

```
$('#mediaModal').modal('hide');
```

On the primary modal, it simply calls `$('#mediaModal').modal('show');` each time the 'Upload Media' button is clicked.

To combat this, I have tried to manually adjust the main `modal` css width before it is shown, like this:

```
$('#mediaModal').modal().on('show', function() {
    $(this).find('.modal').css({
        width: '60%'
    });
});
```

This should make sure the primary modal windows width stays at the original definition of 60%. However, it makes no difference. The first time the modal is open, it represents 60% of the screen in width. Any subsequent openings, it has shrunk down in size. It doesn't continue to shrink after the first hide, but neither can I get it to retain the original desired width.

One last note - it is only changing the width, probably because this is a percentage value.

Thanks for any help! I'm really not that good at CSS so I'm guessing you CSS wizards will know whats happening almost immediately! If I haven't provided enough information please just leave a message and I'll add to this post.

(Note: Upgrading to BS 3 is just not an option, the code base would take weeks to clean up)

Comment: @Thunda Thank you! I'll add that to the post. It is Bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: the best way to debug this is using the browser's inspect element, you will see all the css styles that are being applied over the element, where they come from, and you can disable/edit each one right there